# phase of current relative to voltage using a single resistor

Tags: multisim

I am trying to simulate on Multisim the phase of current relative to voltage using a single 1k resistor. However I can't understand how can I do that.

In this example the oscilloscope shows me voltage different, but I need to see current relative to voltage, not volts to volts.

[image: In this example oscilloscope shows me voltage different]

Thanks.

Comment: Theres nothing to get your head around. You current and voltage are in phase as a resistor has 0 phase angle.  You can see this on your scope if you pretend one of them is voltage the the other current as the current and voltage will reach 0 at the same time. If you had inductors and capacitors in the circuit, these components can induce phase differences.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYt2fh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The OP's schematic redrawn. Voltmeters replace the oscilloscope.*

When we redraw your circuit, omit the crossed lines, put a nice ground rail at the bottom and orient the resistors as shown it becomes immediately clear that you have created a simple voltage divider with a ratio of 2:1.

Oscilloscopes are voltage measurement devices unless fitted with a current sensing probe. To measure current we can use a probe or a shunt resistor to convert current to voltage as per Ohm's Law. This is, in effect, what R2 is doing.

> I am trying to simulate on Multisim the phase of current relative to voltage using a single 1k resistor. However I can't understand how can I do that.

You have succeeded. Congratulations. For a resistor-only circuit the voltage and current are in phase as shown on your trace.

> In this example the oscilloscope shows me voltage different, but I need to see current relative to voltage, not volts to volts.

You are seeing the conversion of the current to a voltage. Since your converter is a resistor, R2, the voltage represents the current with a conversion of 1000 mV/mA or 1 V/mA.

When you've got your head around this then try replacing R1 with a capacitor and observe the phase shift. If you have any inductors - or even a relay coil or motor repeat the experiment with them and observe the shift.

I use "C-I-V-I-L" to remind myself that "In a C the I leads the V which leads the I in an L". That is, current leads voltage in a capacitor and voltage leads current in an inductor.